# Laravel - How to delete record based on condition

Tags: laravel

In my Laravel-5.8, I have these three (3) models:

**Parameter**

```
class Parameter extends Model
{    
    protected $table = 'parameters';
    protected $primaryKey = 'id';
    protected $fillable = [
                  'max_score',
                  'min_score',
                  'identity_id',
              ];

    public function identity()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\Identity','identity_id');
    }
}
```

**Identity**

```
class Identity extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'identity';

    protected $fillable = [
              'id',
              'name',
          ];

    public function goals()
    {
       return $this->hasMany('App\Models\Goal');
    }  

    public function parameter()
    {
       return $this->hasOne(Parameter::class, 'identity_id');
    }    
}
```

**Goal**

```
class Goal extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'goals';

    protected $fillable = [
                  'id',
                  'identity_id',
                  'title',
              ]; 

    public function identity()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\Identity','identity_id');
    }        
}
```

From the model, `Identity` has a foreign key (`identity_id`) in `Parameter`, also `Identity` has foreign key (`identity_id`) in `Goal`.

I have this controller in Identity:

```
public function destroy($id)
{
    try 
    {          
        $identity = Identity::findOrFail($id);
        $identity->delete();
        Session::flash('success', 'Record deleted successfully.');
        return redirect()->back();
    } 
    catch (Exception $exception) {
            Session::flash('error', 'Record delete failed!.');
            return redirect()->back();
    }       
}
```

I want the user to delete `Identity` Record based on these conditions:

1. As the user tries to delete `Identity`, the application should check `Parameter` table and also delete the record where `identity_id` foreign key exist.
2. Secondly, if record with `identity_id` exists in `Goal` table, the application should prevent the delete.

How do I adjust `public function destroy($id)` to achieve this?

Comment: you can put both condition in your database foreign key declaration `ON DELERE CASCADE` & `ON DELETE RESTRICT`. If you want it in the code, put the code you have tried so far so we can help you understand what did not work.

Comment: Is this an `atomic` transaction? Meaning should the `parameter` relation be deleted even if there are `goal` relations?

Answer (score 0):

you can add a function like "deleteAll()" in your 'Identify' Model and delete parameter using relation like this:

```html
class Identity extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'identity';

    protected $fillable = [
        'id',
        'name',
    ];

    public function goals()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Models\Goal');
    }

    public function parameter()
    {
        return $this->hasOne(Parameter::class, 'identity_id');
    }

    public function deleteAll(){
        if(!$this->goals){
            $this->parameter->delete();
            return parent::delete();
        }
        return;
    }
}
```

Comment: How do I now call this:  deleteAll() in controller

Comment: just like any other relation like.... 
$identity = Identity::findOrFail($id);
$identity->deleteAll(); @mikefolu

Answer (score 0):

First in your migrations in the `identity` you need to do like

```
$table->foreign('identity_id')->references('id')->on('parameters')->onDelete('cascade');
```

So when you delete the `Identity` the related `Parameter` will be deleted automatically on database level.
To prevent delete (your mentioned 2 case), you need to check like this

```
$identity = Identity::with('goals')->findOrFail($id);
if($identity->goals){
   // you can throw some error here
}
```